# How can I reduce a formula to the form I want using mathematica

Tags: equation-solving

I have a formula as follows

```
E^((2 \[Pi] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(r\), \(0\), \(2\)]\) (r (2 ArcTan[r/
        Subscript[r, 0]] - 2 Log[r + Subscript[r, 0]] + Log[r^2 + 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(r\), \(0\), \(2\)]\)]) + (2 ArcTan[r/
        Subscript[r, 0]] + 4 Log[Subscript[r, 0]] - 
      2 Log[r + Subscript[r, 0]] - Log[r^2 + 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(r\), \(0\), \(2\)]\)]) Subscript[r, 
    0]) Subscript[\[Rho], 0])/r)
```

May I ask how to use mathematica to simplify it to the following form
[image]

I got by using Collect

```
Collect[1/r 2 \[Pi] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(r\), \(0\), \(2\)]\) (r (2 ArcTan[r/
         Subscript[r, 0]] - 2 Log[r + Subscript[r, 0]] + Log[r^2 + 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(r\), \(0\), \(2\)]\)]) + (2 ArcTan[r/
         Subscript[r, 0]] + 4 Log[Subscript[r, 0]] - 
       2 Log[r + Subscript[r, 0]] - Log[r^2 + 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(r\), \(0\), \(2\)]\)]) Subscript[r, 
     0]) Subscript[\[Rho], 0], ArcTan[r/Subscript[r, 0]]]
```

From here, we can see that the item containing arctan has been aligned, but I don't know what command to use to simplify the remaining item to the form I want? Could you please help me to see it?

Comment: `Simplify`, `FullSimplify`?

Comment: I've tried this and it doesn't seem to do what I want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This gets close to what you want. The trick is to expand the argument of `Exp` first. I changed your subscripts to indexed variables so I can read the code.

Try this variation, which works also for your second example

```
expr=E^((2 π r[0]^2 (r (2 ArcTan[r/r[0]]-2 Log[r+r[0]]+Log[r^2+r[0]^2])+(2 ArcTan[r/r[0]]+4 Log[r[0]]-2 Log[r+r[0]]-Log[r^2+r[0]^2]) r[0]) ρ[0])/r);
expr=expr/. Exp[x_]:>Times@@Map[Exp,List@@Expand[x]]
expr/.Exp[x_]:>Exp[Simplify[x]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And

```
expr=E^((4π r[0]^2 (r (2 Log[r]+Log[1+r[0]^2/r^2])+(π-2 ArcTan[r[0]/r]) r[0])ρ[0])/r)
expr=expr/. Exp[x_]:>Times@@Map[Exp,List@@Expand[x]]
expr/.Exp[x_]:>Exp[Simplify[x]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Old answer**

```
expr = E^((2 π r[0]^2 (r (2 ArcTan[r/r[0]] - 2 Log[r + r[0]] + 
           Log[r^2 + r[0]^2]) + (2 ArcTan[r/r[0]] + 4 Log[r[0]] - 
           2 Log[r + r[0]] - Log[r^2 + r[0]^2]) r[0]) ρ[0])/r);

expr/. {Exp[x_]:>Exp[Expand[x]]}//Simplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This method seems to be invalid for the following expressions?E^((4 \[Pi] r[
  0]^2 (r (2 Log[r] + Log[1 + r[0]^2/r^2]) + (\[Pi] - 
      2 ArcTan[r[0]/r]) r[0]) \[Rho][0])/r)

Comment: @sfks try the updated version to see if it works better

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help me solve this problem! ：）